# How to overlay texture materials on top of each other in Unity 2D tiled game

Tags: c#, unity, sprites, tilemap

I'm learning how to do a 2D tile-based game. So far, I have followed [this tutorial](http://studentgamedev.blogspot.no/2013/08/unity-voxel-tutorial-part-1-generating.html) which seems like a good starting point.

With his method of building the raw triangles and then applying the uvs, I do not understand how I would go about layering other materials on top.

The code he's using to generate the tilebased grid:

```
  float x = transform.position.x;
  float y = transform.position.y;
  float z = transform.position.z;

  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y  , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y  , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y-1 , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y-1 , z ));

  newTriangles.Add(0);
  newTriangles.Add(1);
  newTriangles.Add(3);
  newTriangles.Add(1);
  newTriangles.Add(2);
  newTriangles.Add(3);

  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y));

  mesh.Clear ();
  mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray();
  mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
  mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray(); // add this line to the code here
  mesh.Optimize ();
  mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
```

This is his texture import (Notice he isn't using Sprites):

[image]

I want many items on the grid: terrain, enemies, trees, clouds, cursor.

These would have to be layered on top of each other somehow. An ordering could be:

- Layer 0: Base Terrain
- Layer 1: Trees
- Layer 2: Enemies
- Layer 3: Clouds
- Layer 4: Mouse Cursor

I know that the `SpriteRenderer` has a `Sorting Layer` that does the layering for you. However, the author in the tutorial does not use Sprites, so using the Sorting Layer doesn't seem to be an option? He is using `Texture Type: Advanced` when importing the texture and then chooses some options.

The only other way I can think of is to logically represent different layers by using a different z-index for each logical layer. But I've read that this will cause clipping/artifact issues when rendering, and so using the Sorting Layer is preferred.

If using Sprites is the way to go, could I still use the author's way to generating tiles? The way he's doing it seems pretty efficient since he's building the triangles together to form one tile instead of using a plane/gameobject. I imagine that reassigning the uvs to the triangles is also pretty efficient. I don't quite understand how Sprites can be used on top of what the author has done or how overlaying should be done if using sprites is not possible.

I'm using Unity 4.5.5.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem as this and the only solution I came up with was to have the background and such objects in it's own mesh and likewise for the front... Then I scratched that and went to gameobjects for tiles and implemented a chunking and distance algorithm that loads and unloads chunks... I didn't experience any lag issues either and I had enough flexibility to control layers etc...

Comment: @Savlon Was there a reason you switched from generating the tri/uv to gameobjects? Was it too difficult to manage the overlaying or maybe it was clipping issues? How many gameobjects could your camera render at once? That option might not be possible for me if that number is too low. Ideally I would like to render maybe 50x50 grid with each tile having some object (ie, trees, enemies, clouds...). So that's 100x100 game objects?

Comment: yeh the reason for changing was it was way too high above my pay grade to figure out a way to manage it all... Well I can generate 10 x 10 (100) chunks of 16 x 16 (256) which amounts to 25,600 individual tiles, and the only performance hit I get isn't too extreme (20-30fps).. but when I am instantiating the new chunks and removing the old ones it gets lower (5-10fps)... Btw, this was a test to check the limits and the terrain usually only renders 2 x 2 chunks which are the only chunks visible :) (120+fps)